# UIViewController, storyboards, no init method

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am using storyboards, and I have one `UIViewController` that is being opened modally.

When the `UIViewController` is being loaded, it never hits any of the init methods 
`init`, `initwithcoder`, or `initwithnib`.

Why not? 
I need to initialize some variables there!!

Comment: have you check viewdidload method?

Comment: Use either awakeFromNib or viewDidLoad

Comment: It has to hit initWithCoder.

Answer (score 1):

awakeFromNib was the answer, @Fogmiester got it, don't know how to make it his answer though!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use viewDidLoad function and it also call once for each control object.

Thanks

Comment: This is not the same thing...`viewDidLoad` does not necessarily get called at the same time as an init.